# Everyrow works with tabu but not with longtabu

Tags: longtable, tabu

I've been wrestling with `longtable`s/`longtabu` for a while now, and I have it almost working the way I want.  The last thing that I want to be able to do is have a `\hline` inserted for every row.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\everyrow{\hline} % If I comment out this, or use anything but \hline it works
\begin{longtabu}{|X|X|X|}
First & First & First \\
\endfirsthead
Rest & Rest & Rest \\
\endhead
Foot & Foot & Foot \\
\endfoot
Last & Last & Last \\
\endlastfoot
hello & banana & world
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.18 \end{longtabu}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Seems like a bug in `tabu`. It works with `\everyrow{\tabucline-}`. Do not expect, that the author fixes this supposed bug.

Comment: Related to my latest comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI/jkNlDkpG5cMJ (GL is Florent Chervet, the writer of package `tabu`).

Comment: rather than mess with \every... why not just end each row with `\mycr` defined as `\newcommand\mycr{\\\hline}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use the `\every..` hooks it is simpler to use `\mycr` rather than `\\` to end the table rows, defined as

```
 \newcommand\mycr{\\\hline}
```